# Fetch rows that correspond to the state of the application at some point in history

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not certain how to describe my problem in words so I've created an illustration to help.

```
|-------------------------------------------|
| version_table (many-to-many)              |
|-------------------------------------------|
| version_id | a_id | b_id | operation_type |
|------------|------|------|----------------|
| 1          | 1    | 1    | INSERT         |
| 1          | 1    | 2    | INSERT         |
| 2          | 1    | 1    | DELETE         |
| 3          | 1    | 2    | DELETE         |
|------------|------|------|----------------|
```

In this table querying for each version would yield these results:

1. Version 1 should return two rows (obvious because of the inserts).
2. Version 2 should return one row (less obvious but the row exists until a DELETE operation has been called).
3. Version 3 should return zero rows (all rows cleared by the previous DELETE operations).

Its obvious is that we need to fetch all of the rows that were inserted before or on the supplied version.

```
WHERE table.version_id <= :VERSION
```

But whats not obvious is how we exclude rows that have been "DELETED".

```
AND table.version_id > alias.version_id AND alias.operation_type = "DELETE"
```

This is the query I ended up writing:

```
SELECT tag.id AS tag_id, tag.name AS tag_name 
FROM tag
JOIN article_tag_version ON article_tag_version.tag_id = tag.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN article_tag_version AS article_tag_version_1 ON
    article_tag_version_1.tag_id = tag.id AND
    article_tag_version_1.operation_type = "DELETE"
WHERE article_tag_version.version_id <= ? AND article_tag_version.version_id > article_tag_version_1.version_id
```

...but it doesn't return the results in the way I expect (no results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with a `NOT EXISTS` if the "thing" (whatever it is) has been deleted in a version between the version it was inserted and the target version.

```
SELECT *
       FROM version_table v1
       WHERE v1.operation_type = 'INSERT'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM version_table v2
                                    WHERE v2.version_id >= v1.version_id
                                          AND v2.version_id <= :VERSION
                                          AND (v2.a_id,
                                               v2.b_id) = (v1.a_id,
                                                           v1.b_id)
                                          AND v2.operation_type = 'DELETE')
             AND v1.version_id <= :VERSION;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/65df9/3)

Answer (score 1):

I would just select the most recent record for each `a_id`/`b_id` pair, then filter out the ones that are deleted:

```
select atv.*
from (select distinct on (a_id, b_id) atv.*
      from article_tag_version atv
      where version <= ?  -- the version you care about
      order by a_id, b_id, version desc
     ) atv
where operation_type <> 'DELETE';
```